# How to vertically center one div but not another?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div with 2 children divs. So, in this example, how would I vertically center the `.tagline-container` but not the `nav`?

```
<div class="header">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <h1>Rainey 13 Foundation</h1>
      <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Donate</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="tagline-container">
      <h1 class="tagline">Fostering the First Steps, and Beyond!</h1>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS

```
.header {
  background-image: url(./img/background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.tagline-container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This currently doesn't center anything

My full code

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: NATS;
  src: url(./fonts/NATS-Regular.ttf);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: NATS;
}

.header {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(./img/background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.tagline-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Rainey 13 Foundation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <span>Rainey 13 Foundation</span>
      <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Donate</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="tagline-container">
      <h1 class="tagline">Fostering the First Steps, and Beyond!</h1>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: tagline-container dont have ending </div>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `align-self` on the `.tagline-container`. Align Self adjusts that element on the cross-axis of your flex direction (in this case vertically, since `row` is the default direction):

```css
.header {
  background-image: url(./img/background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.tagline-container {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <h1>Rainey 13 Foundation</h1>
    <ul class="nav-items">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Donate</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="tagline-container">
    <h1 class="tagline">Fostering the First Steps, and Beyond!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Bootstrap Version

You can add `align-self` to the nav.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: NATS;
  src: url(./fonts/NATS-Regular.ttf);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: NATS;
}

.header {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(./img/background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.tagline-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Rainey 13 Foundation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <span>Rainey 13 Foundation</span>
      <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Donate</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="tagline-container">
      <h1 class="tagline">Fostering the First Steps, and Beyond!</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this centers the nav as well

Comment: @JordanBaron the nav is not centered. Run the snippet and open it up in full screen.

Comment: @JordanBaron You left off Bootstrap in your original code. I updated my answer to include the Bootstrap answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to set `.tagline-container` to `flex` layout for implementing `justify-content` and `align-items`.

Based on `flex` layout, it will work as you expected.

```css
.header {
  background-image: url(./img/background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.tagline-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Rainey 13 Foundation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <nav class="main-navbar">
      <span>Rainey 13 Foundation</span>
      <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Donate</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="tagline-container">
      <h1 class="tagline">Fostering the First Steps, and Beyond!</h1>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this centers the nav as well

Comment: On the above snippet, it does not center the navs.

Comment: I put this in my own code and it does center the nav

Comment: Can you show me your code snippet you have tried? It seems there is something I don't know which is not posted on the question.

Comment: I see the problem. It's not the problem of my code. I have seen, you have imported `bootstrap` library and it happened because of that. Bootstrap provides default `.nav` class with this style. `position: relative;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
-ms-flex-pack: justify;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: .5rem 1rem;
}`.

To avoid this, the easiest way is to change the name `.navbar` to the other name like `.main-navbar` so not to use the default bootstrap class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin: auto` inside the `tagline-container`

```css
.header {
  background-image: url(./img/background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.tagline-container {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <h1>Rainey 13 Foundation</h1>
      <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Donate</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="tagline-container">
      <h1 class="tagline">Fostering the First Steps, and Beyond!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this centers the nav as well

Comment: please run the code snippet,  since margin:auto is set inside tagline-container, only tagline-container will be centered.

Comment: I ran it and it does. I also put it in my code and it centered the nav along with the tagline-container

Comment: that's because `.navbar` is already customed styled by the bootstrap framework.